# Calling jython code from python

Tags: python, python-3.x, hbase, jython

I was writing some code in python that needs to write/read to HBase. I thought of using HappyBase to interact with the HBase before I found out that it is not yet for python3.

What I'm thinking is to write a tiny package in jython to interact with the HBase. Rest of the  business logic will remain in Cpython.

Is it possible to call a jython code from python. I want my code to be on CPython except from the section that should interact with HBase

I would be highly grateful if you could give me some hints/examples on how to do that? Do I need specific version of jython interpreter to mix with python3?

**Edit**: Could anybody please recommend how should HBase be accessed using python3?

Comment: Hey @Mayank, I have exactly the same requirement as you. Did you find a solution to this problem?

Comment: @MatthewMoisen Sorry for the late response but, I didn't find an answer yet.

Comment: I ended up implementing Pyro4 to get this accomplished. You have to use version 4.34 on both the Jython and Python side. There are some limitations, notably you cant send a huge payload from python to jython (but you can from jython to python) or it will throw an error -- so you have to batch up payloads and send them over one at a time to jython.

Answer (score 4):

In my experience, [Pyro4](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pyro4) is the easiest CPython/Jython interop package.

Comment: Make sure to use only Pyro4.34 at most, on both Python and Jython, or else it will fail in the later versions.